# Run a function in py file on import

Tags: python-3.x, interpreter, read-eval-print-loop

I've written an interpreter in python, saved it to a `.py` file. To use it in my jupyter notebook I type-

```
import galickgun #galickgun is the interpreter name
galickgun.read_eval_printloop()
#GalickGun>
```

this function asks for an input and I enter my new language syntax in the input and get and an output. Everything is fine there.

I'd like to run the `read_eval_printloop` function as soon as import the `.py` file for the interpreter in my python environment. As in -

```
import galickgun
#GalickGun>
```

Are there better ways to do this? What are some ways I can interact with this new "language".

Comment: To do what you want to do, simply call the method inside `galickgun`, so once you import it, it will execute the method. This, however, is not a suggested/common practice in Python.

Comment: You could have the method inside `if __name__ == '__main__'` of the `galickgun` module and then from your command shell -> `python -m galickgun` instead. That could be another solution to consider as well.